# Reversing a removal of an event handler caused by the .off() method with another button

Tags: jquery

I been searching for hours on google trying to figured this out.

Basically my situation is I have to find a way to **reverse** a removal of an event handler caused by the `.off()` method.

In other words, I want to be able to turn back on the event handler for the `p` tags with another button. How can I do that? Here is my code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("click", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    });
    $("#turn-off").click(function(){
        $("p").off("click");
        $('p').css("background-color", "white");
    });
    
    $("#reverse").click(function(){
       //???
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click this paragraph to change its background color.</p>
<p>Click the button below and then click on this paragraph (the click event is removed).</p>

<button id='turn-off'>Remove the click event handler</button>

<button id='reverse'>Reverse the removal of the click event handler</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning it back on is just calling `.on` back again. And, since you are calling `.on` back again, you'll need to suply all the arguments - as you did the first time.

To make it simpler, you could move the code that calls `.on` to a function and use it in the `#reverse` click logic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function turnOn() {
      $("p").on("click", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      });
    }
    turnOn(); // initial setup
    $("#turn-off").click(function(){
        $("p").off("click");
        $('p').css("background-color", "white");
    });
    
    $("#reverse").click(function(){  // or, simply: $("#reverse").click(turnOn);
       turnOn();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click this paragraph to change its background color.</p>
<p>Click the button below and then click on this paragraph (the click event is removed).</p>

<button id='turn-off'>Remove the click event handler</button>

<button id='reverse'>Reverse the removal of the click event handler</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I suggest you use [namespaced events](https://acdcjunior.github.io/jquery-creating-specific-event-and-removing-it-only.html), should save you some headaches in the future (notice the usage of `click.foo` instead of `click`, being `foo` the namespace):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function turnOn() {
      $("p").on("click.foo", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      });
    }
    turnOn(); // initial setup
    $("#turn-off").click(function(){
        $("p").off("click.foo");
        $('p').css("background-color", "white");
    });
    
    $("#reverse").click(turnOn);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click this paragraph to change its background color.</p>
<p>Click the button below and then click on this paragraph (the click event is removed).</p>

<button id='turn-off'>Remove the click event handler</button>

<button id='reverse'>Reverse the removal of the click event handler</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is upsetting, so we cannot gather event handlers after they set in a temp variable until the `$("#reverse").click(...` to put them back?